# How to serialize select class fields to JSON string using the Builder Pattern in Java and Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson, builder, jsonserializer

I created a User class with a Builder Pattern for the purpose of serializing it to a JSON String for POST. Now, the requirements have changed and I need the ability to PATCH an existing record, updating one or more fields but not all fields in a recordset. The example below has 5 fields in its User class but imagine if it had 30 or even 40 fields including the int type.

```
import com.google.gson.*;

class User 
{
    //All final attributes
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int age;
    private final String phone;
    private final String address;
 
    private User(UserBuilder builder) {
        this.firstName = builder.firstName;
        this.lastName = builder.lastName;
        this.age = builder.age;
        this.phone = builder.phone;
        this.address = builder.address;
    }
 
    //All getter, and NO setter to provide immutability
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
 
    public static class UserBuilder 
    {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private int age;
        private String phone;
        private String address;
 
        public UserBuilder() {
        }

        public UserBuilder(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public UserBuilder firstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            return this;
        }
        
        public UserBuilder lastName(String lastName) {
            this.firstName = lastName;
            return this;
        }
        public UserBuilder age(int age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }
        public UserBuilder phone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
            return this;
        }
        public UserBuilder address(String address) {
            this.address = address;
            return this;
        }
        //Return the finally consrcuted User object
        public User build() {
            User user =  new User(this);
            return user;
        }
    }
}

public class TestUserBuild {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        User user = new User.UserBuilder().
        //No last name
        //No age
        //No phone
        //no address
        .firstName("Super")
        .build();
                 
        System.out.println(user); // User: Super, null, 0, null, null
                    
        Gson gson = new Gson();
                    
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(user)); // {"firstName":"Super","age":0}
    }
}
```

I didn't specify the age and, yet, there it is in the JSON string. I thought the builder pattern would facilitate creating any number of JSON string permutations, i.e. update the first name and last name, update the first name only, update the age only, update last name and phone number only, etc...

Is the builder pattern approach not the correct solution for this problem? If it is an acceptable solution, how can I leverage the builder pattern to serialize the User class to a JSON string but with only the fields of my choosing? Is there something I can leverage in the Gson library to realize this task such as creating a custom type adapter? Maybe I can create a custom type adapter that takes all field as inputs, checks if each one is NULL, or 0 for Integers, and then build the JSON string with just the deltas.

Answer (score 1):

Your "age" field is worth 0 because "int" has a default value. Use "Integer" if you want the age field to default to null.

Some of the advantages of the Builder pattern are **immutability** (you can choose to allow a class to be modified only at creation time by the builder, removing all setters from the class), and that it's **more concise** for instantiating a class with multiple attributes.

But you don't *need* to keep your Builder pattern immutable. If I understand your need correctly, you could keep the builder pattern for versatility during object creation, and keep the setters on the class to be able to update fields easily.

```
import com.google.gson.*;

class User {
//Your attributes don't need to be final
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;
private String phone;
private String address;

private User(UserBuilder builder) {
    this.firstName = builder.firstName;
    this.lastName = builder.lastName;
    this.age = builder.age;
    this.phone = builder.phone;
    this.address = builder.address;
}

//getters AND setters (omitted for brevity)

//builder class stays as is, omitted for brevity

public class TestUserBuild {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User.UserBuilder()
        .firstName("Super")
        .build();
                 
        //when you need to update
        user.setAge(42);
    }
}
```

The question is, why do you want immutability if you need to update fields periodically? Should you remove the immutability constraint altogether (by leaving setters in the class)? Do you need to be able to update specific combinations of fields according to particular business rules? If the latter is true, I would recommend moving away from an [anemic model](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) (a "bag of getters and setters") and adding domain-specific methods which take care of updating the relevant fields. Your User class would then look like this:

```
class User {
    //Your attributes don't need to be final
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private String phone;
    private String address;

    private User(UserBuilder builder) {
        this.firstName = builder.firstName;
        this.lastName = builder.lastName;
        this.age = builder.age;
        this.phone = builder.phone;
        this.address = builder.address;
    }
    //getters ONLY (omitted for brevity)
    //no setters, only domain-relevant methods which update fields as needed
    public void setIdentity(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public void setCoordinates(String phone, String address) {
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
//builder class stays as is

public class TestUserBuild {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User.UserBuilder()
        .firstName("Super")
        .build();

        //update identity (say, your frontend has an "identity" page with only firstName and lastName on it
        user.setIdentity("Chris", "Neve");
        //your frontend page allowing user to update coordinates
        user.setCoordinates("+331231231", "7th av, NYC");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty for your help. I may have 10 "number" fields so those will have to be converted to Integer or similar to respect NULL. I don't need the Builder class to be immutable but I've seen many examples where it is so I tried to follow best practice. Yes, I need the ability to be flexible and update one or as many fields, per business rules, for PATCH requests. I'll take a look at the anemic model link and apply your code changes, ty. I envision my use case as an API request, so I want the flexibility to dynamically serialize the User object as a JSON string with only deltas.